# Jsoup: Which input field must be posted?

Tags: post, jsoup

I want to find out which input field must posted in my application. I use jsoup post:

My URL: `http://185.47.49.85/login.aspx`

My code:

```
Document doc=new Document("ASD");

try {

    doc=Jsoup.connect("http://185.47.49.85/login.aspx/")
            .data("__EVENTTARGET","")
            .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
            .data("__VIEWSTATE", "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")
    .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "C2EE9ABB")
    .data("__PREVIOUSPAGE", "gsmhLhCPfCvUmPOtmYGZavCSVn8KiXvv_ujJZKgxbGMTMoS7-fB3jUysNlHpjGVqTCuIxlxNA5vnOOF_Jog3vb2j6HKQ3_kOJ6JWUlcAd5c1")
    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", "/wEdAA6lKtoPqg2wpq8JitnIKCzHY3plgk0YBAefRz3MyBlTcHY2+Mc6SrnAqio3oCKbxYbDKjeO0tta9Mov2vsvaZ0VW1VFON8NLemVOIc5oCPrDDbNd+G2gDK/o3KZLpfRls0NLI0sLHtyhUxJ5tRy0Qw1IPPXXbVwmcpXcDunE5ErJXf3ZhkaY4N6/yfgXHrl+bYJKZv54L/IQQgpkqAarNp9zfg78Z8BXhXifTCAVkevd6R7lV3BRrsBFnVFRzoWBlmUuSYZz4ym4FYvndnVPufxn7/4HiQ5iYGPaZqUf85XUUWnddBptMe0iBB5jBDhyiLyP8LBCLgClOePInYX7Jk6")
    .data("txtUserName","111111")
    .data("txtPassword","1111111")
    .data("rcTextBox1", "45652")
    .data("TypeStudents","RAD_DANESHJOO")
    .data("RadCaptcha1_ClientState","45652")
    .data("btn_enter", "????")
    .timeout(30000).post();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return doc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the following parameters aren't generated on the fly by the server:

- __VIEWSTATE
- __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR
- __PREVIOUSPAGE
- __EVENTVALIDATION

If it's the case, use the code to this question: [Submitting a form with Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31190892/363573).

**UPDATE:**
Additionnally, you may find useful also the following answser. It shows [captcha image grabbing with Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34491304/363573).

Comment: @SohrabAsaseh Please see my update. Once you get the captcha image you'll either need to solve it manually or send it to a captcha resolving service.

Comment: thank you for answer,for my url what i do for post data with captcha?sry my english is bad:(

Comment: @SohrabAsaseh Please post a new question and leave the link to it in a comment here.