# How to scrape Google SERPs with Jsoup?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, http-status-code-503

I was trying to scrape links from google using 600 different searches, In the process of this I started getting the following error.

**Error**

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=http://google.com/search/...
```

Now I've done my research and it happens because of google scholar ban restricting you to limited searches and need to solve captch to proceed, which jsoup can't do.

**Code**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/search?q=" + keyWord)
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
.timeout(5000)
.get();
```

*Answers on the internet are extremely vague and doesn't provide a clear solution, someone did mention cookies can solve this issue but haven't said a single thing about "how" to do it.*

Comment: till my knowledge error `5**` comes as internal sever problem , did you check your server configuration??(just asking)

Comment: how do i do this? what am i looking for when I check this?

Comment: @Radioactive Coffe Can you update ur solution here ?Also ,I got the temporary ban from google .How to resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints to improve your scraping:

#### 1. Use proxies

Proxies permit you to reduce chances to get caught by a captcha. You should use between 50 and 150 proxies depending on your average result set. Here are two websites that can provide some proxies: [SEO-proxies.com](http://www.seo-proxies.com/) or [Proxify Switch Proxy](https://proxify.com/switchproxy.shtml?).

```
// Setup proxy
String proxyAdress = "1.2.3.4";
int proxyPort = 1234;
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(proxyAdress, proxyPort))

// Fetch url with proxy
Document doc = Jsoup //
               .proxy(proxy) //
               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2") //
               .header("Content-Language", "en-US") //
               .connect(searchUrl) //
               .get();
```

#### 2. Captchas

If by any mean, you get caught by captcha, you can use some online captcha solving services ([Bypass Captcha](http://bypasscaptcha.com), [DeathByCaptcha](http://www.DeathByCaptcha.com) to name a few). Below is a generic step by step procedure to get the captcha solved automatically:

- Detect captcha error page

--

```
try {

  // Perform search here...

} catch(HttpStatusException e) {
    switch(e.getStatusCode()) {
        case java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAVAILABLE:
            if (e.getUrl().contains("http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=http://google.com/search/...")) {
               // Ask online captcha service for help...
            } else {
               // ...
            }
        break;

        default:
        // ...
    } 
}
```

- Download the captcha image (CI)

--

```
Jsoup                     //
//.cookie(..., ...)       // Some cookies may be needed...
.connect(imageCaptchaUrl) //
.ignoreContentType(true)  // Needed for fetching image
.execute()                //
.bodyAsBytes();           // byte[] array returned...
```

- Send CI to online captcha service online

--

This part depends on the captcha service API. You can find some services in this [8 best captcha solving services](http://scraping.pro/8-best-captcha-solving-services-and-tools/) article.

- Wait for response... (1-2 second(s) is perfect)
- Fill the form with response and send it with Jsoup

  The Jsoup [FormElement](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/FormElement.html) is a life saver here. See this [working sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35267768/363573) for details.

#### 3. Some other hints

The [Hints for Google scrapers](http://scraping.pro/google-scraper-hints/) article can give you some more pointers for improving your code. You'll find the first two hints presented here plus some more:

- *Cookies*: clear them on each IP change or don't use them at all
- *Threads*: You should not open two many connections. [Firefox limits itself to 4 connections](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-proxy) per proxy.
- *Returned results*: append `&num=100` to your url to sent less requests
- *Request rates*: Make your requests look human. You should not send more than 500 requests per 24h per IP.

#### References :

- [How to use Jsoup through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34943161/363573)
- [How to download an image with Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34491304/363573)
- [How to fill a form with Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35267768/363573)
- [FormElement javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/FormElement.html)
- [HttpStatusException javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/HttpStatusException.html)

Comment: You sir are a no.1 legend, I haven't seen this accurate answer in my entire life, you just made my day and probably gonna help alot of people in future who run across this problem

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Stephan answer, you can use this package to get the Google search results without the hassle of proxies. Code sample:

```
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<>();
parameter.put("q", "Coffee");
parameter.put("location", "Portland");
GoogleSearchResults serp = new GoogleSearchResults(parameter);

JsonObject data = serp.getJson();
JsonArray results = (JsonArray) data.get("organic_results");
JsonObject first_result = results.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println("first coffee: " + first_result.get("title").getAsString());
```

[Project Github](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-java)

Comment: This project use "Serpapi" that is a paid product.