# How to login an aspx page with security image capture field using jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm trying to login into a site using JSoup but I'm having trouble getting that.system.out.println show me login not ok!and in emulator just login url shown and nothing happen. help me please 
I'm not sure if the URL or login data is incorrect.

and url is http://amozesh.iaurmia.ac.ir/Default.aspx
I'm currently trying with the following code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        try {
            String urlLogin = "http://amozesh.iaurmia.ac.ir/login.aspx";
            String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36";

            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .userAgent(userAgent)
                    .timeout(0)
                    .execute();

            Document loginPage = response.parse();
        //   if (response.statusCode() == 307) {


               response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin).ignoreHttpErrors(true)

                       // .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                       .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                       .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                       .data("__VIEWSTATE", loginPage.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
                               // .data("__PREVIOUSPAGE", loginPage.getElementById("__PREVIOUSPAGE").val())
                       .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", loginPage.getElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION").val())
                       .data("txtUserName", username)
                       .data("txtPassword", password)
                       .data("TXT_CAPT", amniyat)
                       .data("TypeStudents", "RAD_DANESHJOO")
                       .data("LoginButton", "ورود به سیستم")
                       .userAgent(userAgent)
                       .followRedirects(false)
                       .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                       .timeout(0)
                       .execute();
               if (response.hasHeader("location")) {
                   System.out.println("login ok!!!!");
               } else {
                   System.out.println("login not ok!");
               }
               Map<String, String> loginCookies = response.cookies();
                // cook = loginCookies;


                //Now you can parse any page you want, as long as you pass the cookies
               Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .timeout(0)
                        .cookies(loginCookies)
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .followRedirects(true)
                       .userAgent(
                               "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .get();


                Elements description = doc.select("table");



                // Locate the content attribute
                desc = description.html();


        }
            catch(IOException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set description into TextView

        web= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
      //  web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       // web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        desc = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + desc;

        web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", desc, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        web.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(10);
        web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a captcha solver service for this. Here is what to do:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Create an array
    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {
        String urlLogin = "http://amozesh.iaurmia.ac.ir/login.aspx";
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36";

        // Go to login page
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(urlLogin)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .timeout(0)
                .execute();

        Document loginPage = response.parse();

        // Download the captcha image
        Element imgCaptcha = loginPage.select("#pnlLogin img[alt=Captcha]").first();
        if (imgCaptcha == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate captcha image...");
        }

        byte[] imgData = Jsoup //
            .connect(imgCaptcha.absUrl("src")) //
            .cookies(response.cookies()) //
            .referrer(urlLogin) //
            .ignoreContentType(true) //
            .maxBodySize(0) // Bypass 1MB default limit
            .execute() //
            .bodyAsBytes();

        // Send imgData to the captcha solver service
        // ...

        // Use the response returned by the captcha solver for connecting...
        // ...
     } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return null;
}
```